# RequestSecurityToken from ADFS using windows authentication

Tags: wcf, windows-authentication, adfs2.0

My client should request the security token from the ADFS server using the currently logged on user's context. I have been successfully able to request the security token from the adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed endpoint using username and password from the client and post it to my website.

Here's a snippet of my code.

```
WS2007HttpBinding binding = new WS2007HttpBinding(SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
        binding.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
        binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.None;
        EndpointAddress EpAddress;
        if (!bWindowsAuth)
        {
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.UserName;
            EpAddress = new EndpointAddress(".../adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed");
        }
        else
        {
            binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;
            EpAddress = new EndpointAddress(".../adfs/services/trust/13/windowsmixed");
        }

        WSTrustChannelFactory trustChannelFactory = new WSTrustChannelFactory(binding, EpAddress);
        trustChannelFactory.TrustVersion = TrustVersion.WSTrust13;

        if (!bWindowsAuth)
        {
            trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = username;
            trustChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = password;
        }
        else
        {
            trustChannelFactory.Credentials.Windows.ClientCredential = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        }

        trustChannelFactory.ConfigureChannelFactory();

        // Create issuance issuance and get security token 
        RequestSecurityToken requestToken = new RequestSecurityToken(WSTrust13Constants.RequestTypes.Issue, WSTrust13Constants.KeyTypes.Bearer);
        requestToken.AppliesTo = new EndpointAddress(appliesTo);
        WSTrustChannel tokenClient = (WSTrustChannel)trustChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
        SecurityToken token = tokenClient.Issue(requestToken, out rsts);
```

CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials is empty!!

Any other configurations to be done?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: looks like you need to check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32615043/windows-authentication-with-adfs-on-standalone-application